# Closure object cannot have properties in Laravel middleware

Tags: laravel, exception, properties, closures, laravel-middleware

I want to have a middleware in the constructor of my controller to filter a non AJAX requests:

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    // Return 404 if not AJAX request
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        if (!$request->ajax()) {
            return abort(404);
        }
        return $next;
    }, ['only' => ['list', 'publish', 'unpublish', 'delete']]);
}
```

There is a method in the controller:

```
public function list(Request $request)
{
    die('OK');
}
```

When I make an AJAX request I got the exception: "Closure object cannot have properties".
If I comment out the middleware, everything works fine.

Comment: Have you tried this with a non-closure middleware? I.e. making it a middleware class?

Comment: Not sure if this is related with the error, but your return statement is wrong: It should be `return $next($request);` instead of `return $next;`

Comment: Digging into the framework and I see that controller's middleware method does accept closure. "@param  \Closure|array|string  $middleware", and it is documented at https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/controllers

Comment: I think you meant to "return $next($request);" as @Remul said.

Comment: Guys, you are right. When I return $next($request) it works fine. Thank you!.

Comment: Glad you solved it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your return statement is wrong, you have to return `$next($request);` instead of `return $next;`

I would personally change your code to this:

```
use Illuminate\Http\Response;

public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();

    // Return 404 if not AJAX request
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
        if (! $request->ajax()) {
            abort(Response::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        }

        return $next($request);
    })->only(['list', 'publish', 'unpublish', 'delete']);
}
```